# How to indicate the direction of a vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, vectors, convention

[image]

Here, A and B are the initial and final points of the vector $\vec{AB}$ respectively. We can say that the direction of the vector is from A to B. However, can we also say that the direction of $\vec{AB}$ is from C to D?

Comment: Do you see any problem with this ?

Comment: @KurtG. No, I have no problem with this. I was just wondering if there was any convention that forbids this usage.

Comment: If both of us unambiguously can say what the direction of the vector is any convention would be superfluous.

Comment: Well, you can indeed say $\overset{\rightarrow}{AB}$ points "in the direction of $\overset{\rightarrow}{CD}$. I think more commonly one would say it is simply "parallel to $CD$, or perhaps "at $0^{\circ}$", or, if an axis is defined, you might say "pointing in the positive $x$ direction".

Comment: @tryingtobeastoic If your illustration shows a horizontal line in 2 dimensions, then does the vector have direction $\begin{pmatrix} 4 \cr 0 \end{pmatrix}$ or $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \cr 0 \end{pmatrix}$ or neither or both?

Comment: @ryang Probably both. I don't understand the notations entirely. They are just x and y coordinates, right? The top one is the x-coordinate, and the bottom one is the y-coordinate, right?